# May 12, 2022 pyCharm mouse-wheel scrolling painfully slow

Tags: mouse-scroll, pycharm

I discovered pyCharm update on 2002-05-12 (version 2022.1.1) severely impacted mouse wheel scrolling.

***How do I go back to previous version?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `snap info pycharm-community`:

```
name:      pycharm-community
summary:   PyCharm Community Edition
publisher: jetbrains✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/pycharm-community
contact:   https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/documentation/

(... SNIP ...)

snap-id:      Qo9GiW9eyzgN1tXmWpQ9gdstdFsj4K7E
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: 3 days ago, at 19:33 MDT
channels:
  latest/stable:    2022.1.1 2022-05-12 (278) 592MB classic
  latest/candidate: 2022.1.1 2022-05-12 (278) 592MB classic
  latest/beta:      2022.1.1 2022-05-12 (278) 592MB classic
  latest/edge:      2022.1.1 2022-05-12 (278) 592MB classic
  2022.1/stable:    2022.1.1 2022-05-12 (278) 592MB classic
  2022.1/candidate: 2022.1.1 2022-05-12 (278) 592MB classic
  2022.1/beta:      2022.1.1 2022-05-12 (278) 592MB classic
  2022.1/edge:      2022.1.1 2022-05-12 (278) 592MB classic
  2021.3/stable:    2021.3.3 2022-03-17 (274) 553MB classic
  2021.3/candidate: 2021.3.3 2022-03-17 (274) 553MB classic
  2021.3/beta:      2021.3.3 2022-03-17 (274) 553MB classic
  2021.3/edge:      2021.3.3 2022-03-17 (274) 553MB classic

(... SNIP ...)
```

Notice the previous version is dated `2022-03-17` but is strangely called `2021.3/stable`.

Now issue the command to switch channels:

```
sudo snap switch --channel 2021.3/stable pycharm-community
```

Finally, refresh the snap:

```
sudo snap refresh pycharm-community
```

I had spent a few days putting up with mouse wheel scrolling lag before attempting to fix it. Repairing IDE. Overriding indices. Disabling Smooth Scrolling. The above solution was the only thing that worked.

If you encounter the same problem, I hope this self-answered question helps you.